# Random video play code on homepage suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, html5-video

I'm in charge of maintaining the website of a small foundation dedicated to video art.

On the homepage we used to have a few videos playing randomly when the user clicked on play.

But suddenly a while back it stopped working , the videos won't load on Chrome /Edge /Vivaldi while on Firefox it plays only the last video in the list ...

```
<div class="videosaccueil">
<section id="videos">
            <video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video1.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video2.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video3.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video4.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video5.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video6.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video7.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video8.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video9.mp4"></video>
<video playsinline="" controls="controls" preload="none"><source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/videos/video10.mp4"></video>
</section>      <script><br />
            (function () {<br />
                "use strict";<br />
                var videosSection = document.getElementById("videos");<br />
                var videosSectionClone = videosSection.cloneNode();<br />
                var videos = videosSection.getElementsByTagName("video");<br />
                var randomVideo = videos.item(Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)).cloneNode(true);<br />
                randomVideo.setAttribute("preload", "auto");<br />
                videosSectionClone.appendChild(randomVideo);<br />
                videosSection.parentNode.replaceChild(videosSectionClone, videosSection);<br />
                randomVideo.play();<br />
            })();<br />
        </script>

</div>
```

I wasn't the one that made the random play code and I'm not practical enough to understand what went wrong so It would be really nice if someone can indicate to me how to fix the code if it's possible .

Thank you very much for your help .

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes , this : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: You have `<br>` inside `<script>` tag, you can't do that. Remove all `<br />`

Comment: I removed all the <br /> and it's already a big step ahead !!! Now it actually plays one of the video randomly .  But it keeps playing the same video while it used to jump from one video to the other . Can it be fixed too? Anyway thank you very much Konrad !!!

Comment: @Erik Just create a normal function. `function playRandomVid() { /*code here* /}` instead of the current `(function () {<br /> /* code here */  })();<br />`

Comment: Yes I removed all the <br /> that Wordpress kept adding automatically .   Now the browser plays randomly one of the videos so it's already way better .  In the past it used to jump  from one video to the other .  Is it possible to add a variable so once it played the first video it then move on to another random video ???